# Defining SEO routes with categories in Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, seo, laravel-routing

I am struggling with with defining routes in Laravel that will give the URL hierarchy that I want, I don't even know if it's possible...

So basically this is what I want:

```
/projects                 // Show all projects
/projects/create          // Create a new project
/projects/edit/id         // Edit project with ID
/projects/example         // Show all projects in category example
/projects/example/id/slug // Show project with ID
```

I am using a pattern for the ID :

```
Route::pattern('id', '[0-9]+');
```

I have gotten most of it working, but I am struggling with differentiating `/projects/create` and `/projects/example` (where example can be any category).

My current route config looks like this:

```
Route::get('projects/{cat}/{id}/{slug?}', ['as' => 'projects.show', 'uses' => 'ProjectsController@show']);
Route::get('projects/{cat}', ['as' => 'projects.category', 'uses' => 'ProjectsController@category']);
Route::get('projects/edit/{id}', ['as' => 'projects.edit', 'uses' => 'ProjectsController@edit']);
Route::resource('projects', 'ProjectsController', ['except' => ['show', 'edit']]);
```

Any idea or pointers to how I can solve this? Or some other cleaver way that it might be done?

Comment: How is your route currently being setup? Show your current routes definition

Comment: Added my current route config.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course there are workarounds for this, like adding something artificial (`@`) to the route, or rearranging routes order.

However there is another, solid way to make sure you reach your goal - a pattern:

**UPDATE**: if you would like to add something after `{cat}` part in the url, then you should use the 2nd pattern provided below.

```
// either global
Route::pattern('cat', '^(?!create$).*');
// Route::pattern('cat', '^(?!create$)[^/]*');

// or just for this very route
Route::get('projects/{cat}', ['as' => 'projects.category', 'uses' => 'ProjectsController@category'])
  ->where('cat', '^(?!create$).*');
  // ->where('cat', '^(?!create$)[^/]*');
```

With this pattern your route won't ever match `/projects/create`.

Comment: That is what I have been looking for! Thank you!

Comment: Anyone using this should also check out this reply: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25753253/3903565

Answer (score 0):

I do this for users profiles for example...

Route::get('@{username}', ['as' => 'profile_path', 'uses' => 'UsersController@show']);

The @ symbol gives you a nice indicator on where you are.

Code from laracasts.

Comment: I don't really understand how this works, what does the @ actually do?

Comment: It allows you to pattern match so not to clash with other patterns.

Comment: Use I could e.g. use this for /projects/@username without interfering with the other routes? Interesting... The @ seems better paired with the username than other identifiers. But nice to know :)

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing the categories route, as create me be taken as a category

```
Route::get('projects/{cat}', ['as' => 'projects.category', 'uses' => 'ProjectsController@category']);

Route::get('projects/{cat}', ['as' => 'projects.category', 'uses' => 'ProjectsController@category', 'except' => ['create']]);
```

Comment: Doesn't look like the `except` argument works on `Route::get`.

Answer (score 0):

Since Routes are being read from top to bottom, you likely solution is to re-order your routes.

```
// Matches your resourceful routes (including 'projects/create')
Route::resource('projects', 'ProjectsController', ['except' => ['show', 'edit']]);

// None of the resourceful routes found? Try to match the ones below
Route::get('projects/{cat}/{id}/{slug?}', ['as' => 'projects.show', 'uses' => 'ProjectsController@show']);
Route::get('projects/{cat}', ['as' => 'projects.category', 'uses' => 'ProjectsController@category']);
Route::get('projects/edit/{id}', ['as' => 'projects.edit', 'uses' => 'ProjectsController@edit']);
```

Of course the only caveat here is you can't use 'create' as your project category, which you probably already know.